# In hadiths, how do you know when "knowledge" means religious knowledge or any knowledge?

Tags: hadith

In some hadiths it's clear knowledge of religion is being discussed, some are clear that any knowledge is being discussed, but what about rest. Do all hadiths have context that you can read somewhere. Is there an established approach?

I've come across insincere approaches from two sides, where one side claim every mention of knowledge is only referring to religious knowledge, whereas other side does the opposite. Yet in some case neither have any good justification for their claim. And in most one side is correct based on reasonable conclusion derived from context.

Comment: Alsalam alikum, your question is not really understandable can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Maybe this is related [Why knowledge is often related with religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28696/why-knowledge-is-often-related-with-religion). But it is really unclear what you are trying to say or ask!

Comment: Yes related, but my question is how can you be certain whether particular hadith is referring to religious knowledge or any knowledge.

Comment: There's no difference between both, basically gaining knowledge is fard kifyah, and Muslims should gather both kinds of knowledge or have both in their ummah.  However hadith -as interpreted by scholars- when speaking about knowledge in general refer to knowledge of the religion.

Comment: The hadith about go as far as china if you need knowledge, for example doesn't sound like it's only referring to religious knowledge. Especially since China is very far to have any religious knowledge at that time. So only type of knowledge there would be non-religious type.

Comment: Collectively taken word knowledge seems to refer to all knowledge as there are hadiths and duas that  talk about useful knowledge. There can be lot of non-religious knowledge that can be useful. Medicine, Astronomy, Civil engineering, Carpentry, etc. For example hadith that says person leaves knowledge, children and charity when he dies. Knowledge that continues to benefit others after his death.

Comment: The hadith you mentioned about seeking knowledge as far as China is regarded as fabricated. Nevertheless you may find somebody in China knowing some sunnah which many poeple don't know....